# How to go from STEP geometry to CSG

Tags: python, cad, step, csg

I am trying to transform a solid created in a CAD program (saved in a STEP file) into a [CSG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructive_solid_geometry) object constructed with simple primitives.

I am not very familiar with the different geometry file formats but as far as I understand it should be possible to do, at least with some simple solids, since the information about the face shapes etc. is stored in a STEP file. I have found this issue https://github.com/tpaviot/pythonocc-core/issues/470 which proves you can extract some of this information. However I am not sure this is enough to achieve my goal.

As an example, I would like to go from the following CAD design / STEP file:
[image: Example input geometry]

to a CSG description which should describe the geometry as a big cylinder with three smaller cylinders as subtractions.

Ideally I would use a python library for this purpose, perhaps [this library](https://github.com/tpaviot/pythonocc-core) is a good candidate.

However I am afraid this isn't theoretically possible since I am not finding much information online.

As a last resort I could just mesh the solid and generate a CSG description using a tessellated solid, but I want to use simple primitives such as boxes or cylinders whenever possible.

I would love to know if this is possible to do and if so, I would love some resources to read about this. Thanks!

Comment: Try a google search for "Inverse CSG".  From my brief research, this isn't a super easy problem, and is in active research by the community.  There is a promising paper from 2018 but I haven't found a canned library for this. [https://cdfg.mit.edu/publications/inversecsg-automatic-conversion-3d-models-csg-trees](https://cdfg.mit.edu/publications/inversecsg-automatic-conversion-3d-models-csg-trees)